# Does "find" open files?

Tags: nginx, find

I recently issued this command:
`find . -type f | wc -l`

To count how many files are in my public_html folder.

Shortly after, Nginx returned 500 internal server error and error.log was being flooded with "too many open files" error.  I thought maybe this could be the source of this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at `strace -eopen find . -type f` with GNU find (4.4.2 from Debian Squeeze) the answer appears to be "no, find does not open files", but it *does* open directories:

```
open("details", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
open("..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 5
open("..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 5
open("..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 5
open("..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 5
open("..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 5
open("..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 5
open("..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 5
open("..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 5
open(".uml", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
open("..", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_NOFOLLOW) = 5
open(".dbus", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
```

etc.  Of course all of these commands returned the same filehandle # which strongly implies that find is closing them again.  I made a pretty deep set of directories and it seems that find uses `..` to go up a directory rather than holding the directory open.

It does seem like a really remarkable coincidence though.

Answer (score 0):

Files ARE directories, of course, and if find weren't closing them as it went along, you'd still theoretically be at some tiny risk on some Unixen.  Run the full

```
strace find . -type f
```

and look at the sequence (from linux):

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "a", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
fchdir(6)                               = 0
getdents(6, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 104
getdents(6, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(6)
...
```